# How to serve a flutter-web project using fastapi and integrate Swagger?

Tags: flutter, fastapi, swagger-ui

I am trying to serve a web app. that is built using **Flutter-web** for the front-end, and **fastapi** on top of **Uvicorn** for the back-end. I also, integrated **Swagger** for API documentation, using locally downloaded Swagger files as I want to use Swagger offline.

(This is my project structure)

[image: Project folders]

I am facing trouble serving the **HTML web pages**, as I keep getting **404**.

I try to access the index page using: `localhost:9100/` but, I get 404.
If I change `app.mount` to be like this: `app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="static",html=True))`, I can load the HTML web page, but, neither the APIs nor Swagger will work.

```
app = FastAPI(debug=True,docs_url=None,redoc_url=None)
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static",html=True))

@app.get("/docs", include_in_schema=False)
async def custom_swagger_ui_html():
    return get_swagger_ui_html(
        openapi_url=app.openapi_url,
        title=app.title + " - Swagger UI",
        oauth2_redirect_url=app.swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url,
        swagger_js_url="static/swagger-ui-bundle.js",
        swagger_css_url="static/swagger-ui.css",
    )

@app.post("/start")
def start_app(s:String):
       return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, content={ "data": "test"})
```

What am I missing in here?

Comment: Does `localhost:9100/ index.html` work?

Comment: @isabi No, I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to get the following to all work together:

- APIs
- Web pages
- Locally served Swagger docs

**Solution:**

Change the following line in index.html to be as such, leaving all the above code as is:

```
<base href="/static/">
```

This will allow you to access the web pages above using:

```
localhost:port/static/login
```

And the Swagger docs using:

```
localhost:port/docs
```

I was hoping to make the webpages also working directly without the static part in the URL, but this is the best I could achieve.